# getSharedPreferences(sharedprefname, Context.MODE_PRIVATE) in a broad cast receiver returns null pointer exception?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, sharedpreferences, android-2.2-froyo

**I'm developing an android application.I'm using Android SDK 2.2**

I'm using 2 Broadcast receivers. Receiver A start a service `S1`

Receiver B starts a service `S2`.

Both the receivers invoked at a time interval of 1 hour

Receiver A is invoked @ a time 9.00, 10.00, etc

Receiver B is invoked @ a time 8.50, 9.50, etc

In service S1 I'm storing some data in shared preferences

I'm storing some data in shared preferences in the receiver B.

**I'm using the code below in the BroadcastReceiver for getting shared preference. But it throws null pointer exception**

```
context.getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("myPrefs_capture_gps_per_hour", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

in the code above **context** is the object of the class BusinessModel. This BusinessModel class is the child class of the **Application(android.app.Application)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got  the solution.

The following statement is used to get the shared preferences inside the broadcast receiver

```
mContext.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs_capture_gps_per_hour", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

In the above code **"mContext"** is the context passed in the **onReceive()** method